# VBA sheets.activate will not change the sheet it takes information from

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am trying to change worksheet during run-time so I wrote this code in VBA:

```
 Dim Item As Variant
 Dim Info As Variant
 Dim Stat As Integer
 Stat = 2
 Dim Line As Integer
 Line = 1
 Item = "Cases"
 Sheets(Item).Activate
 Do
        Line = Line + 1
 Loop While Cells(Line, "B") <> Null
 Do
     Info = Cells(1, Stat)
     Info = InputBox("what is the item " & Info & "?")
     Cells(Line, Stat) = Info
 Loop While Cells(1, Stat) <> Null
```

the activate function does open the worksheet named "Cases" just like I wanted, but when this part runs "Info = Cells(1, Stat)" it still takes the information from the last worksheet even though I see the "Cases" worksheet.

I looked in another vba code I wrote which I used the same method, it worked there but I couldn't find anything different I did there that could make it work there and was missing here.

Comment: In general you want to avoid `Activate`. Even though [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) is mainly about avoiding `Select`, give it a read, especially the parts about being *explicit* about the worksheet and workbook.

Comment: i already tried writing the exact path i need, it's just make the code to crash

Comment: You shouldn't need to write the path except when you `Open` the workbook.

Comment: Nothing is ever going to be `Null` in Excel, for one. Finding the last row doesn't need a loop: you want `Line = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cases").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the sheet into its own local variable, you don't need to `Activate` anything (if you have a `Workbook` object, use it in place of `ActiveWorkbook` to qualify the `Worksheets` call).

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cases")
```

Now get the last/next row without looping:

```
Dim line As Long
line = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Now, your loop condition isn't going to work, because nothing in Excel is ever going to be `Null`. Rather, look for `Empty` cells, and use the `ws` variable to qualify *every* single `Cells` member call:

```
Do
    Info = ws.Cells(1, Stat).Value
    Info = InputBox("what is the item " & Info & "?")
    ws.Cells(Line, Stat).Value = Info
Loop While Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(1, Stat).Value)
```

Comment: that works exactly as i wanted, thank you very much.
now i just try to figure out how on the other VBA cod it did work the way i tried here